# systemtap: how to determine probe events and args

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf, systemtap

I'm trying to find out the reason for these writes to my flash drive.

```
deathstar> while true
> do
> dmesg|grep sdc|grep WRITE
> sleep 3
> done
[17967.580179] kworker/u4:2(6863): WRITE block 20971648 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[17967.580206] kworker/u4:2(6863): WRITE block 20971784 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[17967.580214] kworker/u4:2(6863): WRITE block 20971832 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[17967.580222] kworker/u4:2(6863): WRITE block 21037080 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
```

I ran:

> perf record -g -a

and then

> perf report -s comm

to get

```
-    0.10%     0.10%     kworker/u4:2                                                                    ▒
     ext4_bio_write_page                                                                                 ▒
     strnlen                                                                                             ▒
     elv_rqhash_del.isra.5.part.6                                                                        ▒
     find_get_pages                                                                                      ▒
     find_get_pages_tag                                                                                  ▒
     scsi_init_io                                                                                        ◆
     ext4_mb_use_inode_pa                                                                                ▒
     cpuacct_charge                                                                                      ▒
     i915_gem_retire_requests_ring                                                                       ▒
     cfq_insert_request                                                                                  ▒
     i915_gem_free_request                                                                               ▒
     __wake_up_bit                                                                                       ▒
     i915_gem_object_move_to_inactive                                                                    ▒
     bdi_wakeup_thread_delayed                                                                           ▒
     __test_set_page_writeback                                                                           ▒
     scsi_request_fn                                                                                     ▒
     ext4_group_desc_csum                                                                                ▒
     __pagevec_lru_add_fn                                                                                ▒
     clear_page_dirty_for_io                                                                             ▒
     wb_writeback                                                                                        ▒
     cfq_service_tree_add                                                                                ▒
     cache_grow                                                                                          ▒
     __writeback_inodes_wb
```

How do i now use: **ext4_bio_write_page** within *systemtap* to print various arguments.. how do i even determine what the possible args are?
I want to do something like:

```
 > stap -v -e 'probe ext4.ext4_bio_write_page?? { printf("%s %d", ???
```

and extract something interesting like maybe buffer_size or file_name - i don't know what specifically (i want to go through those functions one by one and look at their signatures).

[please note i'm totally new to this so i may have made some very stupid mistakes]

Comment: the docs do mention *man stapprobes* but i couldn't find anything ext4 related in there

Comment: i tried something like: stap -v -e 'probe module("ext4").function("ext4_bio_write_page") {printf("hello\n");  }' which is useless but works - i need the params for ext4_bio_write_page

Comment: stap -v -e 'probe module("ext4").function("ext4_bio_write_page") {printf("hello %s (%s)\n", $$vars, $$parms);  }' prints out useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [systemtap tutorial](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/tutorial/) section 2.2 "what to print" and section 3.2 "target variables".  A brief excerpt:

```
{ println($$vars) }
```

prints all variables in scope.  `$foo$` pretty-prints the `foo` object, including one level of struct subfields.  `$foo$$` pretty-prints deeply (subject to `MAXSTRINGLEN` limits).

```
# stap -L 'kernel.function("foo")'
```

will print out the list of variables in scope of function `foo`.

Comment: thank you for the tutorial - i had figured out the answer but that tutorial is excellent.